# Почему не работает lazy initialization в hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

Не работает ленивая инициализация в hibernate.
Вот классы

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PERSONS")
public class Persons {

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "person", cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
    public List<Cards> cards = new ArrayList<Cards>();

    public Persons() {
    }
    //getters and setters
```

}

Класс Cards

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CARDS")
public class Cards {

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "card", cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
    @JsonManagedReference
    public List<BalanceHist> balanceHists = new ArrayList<BalanceHist>();

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "card", cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
    @JsonManagedReference
    public List<Events> events = new ArrayList<Events>();

//getters and setters
}
```

Если посмотреть что приходит в json'е на фронт то видно следующее:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видно из картинки метод отрабатывает, хотя я должен получить ошибку, так как если посмотреть на метод получения пользователей в DAO:

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public class PersonRepository extends AbstractRepository<Persons> {
    public PersonRepository() {
        super(Persons.class);
    }

    @Override
    public List<Persons> getAll() {
        return super.getAll();
    }
}
```

Класс родитель для DAO:

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public abstract class AbstractRepository<Entity> {

    private Class persistentClass;

    public AbstractRepository(Class persistentClass) {
        this.persistentClass = persistentClass;
    }



    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    protected Session getSession() {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }

    public List<Entity> getAll() {
        return getSession().createCriteria(persistentClass).list();
    }

}
```

То есть я нигде не инициализирую поля сущностей помеченных аннотацией `@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "card", cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)`, и по идеи должен получать ошибку при обращении к ним, но у меня почему сразу тянутся все зависимости из БД. Подскажите в чем может быть проблема.

```
        @Repository
    @Transactional
    public class PersonRepository extends AbstractRepository<Persons> {
        public PersonRepository() {
            super(Persons.class);
        }


        @Autowired
        private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
        protected Session getSession() {
            return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        }

        @Override
        public List<Persons> getAll() {
    //        Criteria criteria = createEntityCriteria();
    //        criteria.addOrder(Order.asc("personId"));
    //        return criteria.list();
            List<Persons> personsList =  getSession().createCriteria(Persons.class).list();
            for (Persons persons : personsList) {
                Hibernate.initialize(persons.getCards());
            }
            return personsList;
        }
}


    @Service
@Transactional
public class PersonService {

    public List<Persons> getUsers() {
        List<Persons> personList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Persons person : personRepository.getAll()) {
            if (person.getRole().getRoleType().equals("USER"))
                personList.add(person);
        }
        return personList;
    }

}



   @Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class AppController {

    @RequestMapping(value = {"/", "/home"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String homePage(ModelMap model) {
        model.addAttribute("greeting", "Welcome to the first page of the project");

        System.out.println("ASASAS");
        for (Persons person: personService.getUsers()) {
            for (Cards card:person.getCards()) {
                System.out.println("TROLOLO");
                System.out.println(card.getCardName());
                if (Const.DEBUG) {
                    if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
                        logger.debug(card.getCardName());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return "welcome";

    }
}
```

Comment: покажите как вы вызываете метод getAll, он тоже объявлен как transactional?

Comment: ArtemKonovalov, не совсем понял. Разве недостаточно добавить аннотацию @Transactional к классу, который представляет слой DAO?

Comment: дело в том, что если сериализация объекта происходит в рамках транзакции то lazy сработает так как надо. Потому что, сессия с бд еще не прервана и hibernate или что там у вас может сделать еще запрос и достать недостающие объекты.

Comment: да, сейчас проверил и понял, что не работает lazy инициализация

Comment: @ArtemKonovalov можете объяснить принцип инициализации. Я делал по туториалу https://howtoprogramwithjava.com/hibernate-eager-vs-lazy-fetch-type/, но почему-то не работает, и у меня вопрос: я в методе getUsers должен сам карты к пользователю присоединять, или Hibernate сам может это сделать?

Comment: Покажите код который вызывает метод getAll он тоже выполняется в транзакции или нет? А что за ошибка, дополните вопрос. Без этой информации мои экстрасенсорные возможности бессильны.

Comment: @ArtemKonovalov, метод getAll вызывается не в транкзации

Comment: @ArtemKonovalov, добавил код. У меня есть прослойка - сервис. Вызываю метод getAll через метод getUsers сервиса и  все это вызывается в методе контроллера. Ошибка не выскакивает, так как данные не цепляются. И у меня вопрос я правильно данные цепляю через Hibernate.initialize(persons.getCards()); или я должен свою реализацию присоединения карточек писать?

Comment: Я не понимаю, вы выше пишите что у вас объекты сразу все выбираются из бд. Но вы же явно их инициализируется Hibernate.initialize, т.ч. тут нет никакого противоречия.

Comment: @ArtemKonovalov я решил проверить, работает ли lazy инициализация и поменял метод, добавив туда Hibernate.initialize(persons.getCards());. В итоге когда я в контроллере пытаюсь вывести список карт для каждого пользователя, я получаю null, хотя вызываю метод с Hibernate.initialize(persons.getCards());. До этого я пробовал вызывать метод без Hibernate.initialize(persons.getCards()); и тоже получал null. То что на фронт идет я вообще понять не могу, так как там пол базы в запросе уходит (думаю это как-то связано с json объектами)

Comment: попробуйте в метода дао, явно пробежаться по коллекции и посмотреть что возвращается. Возможно вам придется в сервисе начать транзакцию, получить объекты сериализовать их в json и только после этого закрыть транзакцию. Или в дао явно делать инициализацию lazy полей.

Comment: Возвращается null, коллекция пустая

Comment: Значит нужно проверять mapping, видимо есть несоответствие между названием таблиц, полей в коде и тем что в бд.

Comment: @ArtemKonovalov, если мапинги не верные, как тогда на фронт отправляются данные?

Comment: а как они отправляются?  используется тоже dao?

Comment: используется сервис которые вызывает дао. Причем отправляется не коллекция карт, а коллекция пользователей, к которой цепляется коллекция карт, к коллекции карт цепляются ещё коллекции и так далее, хотя везде стоят fetch=LAZY и по идеи null вместо коллекций должны идти. Попробовал сейчас вывести коллекцию всех карт через ДАО для карт, все вывелось успешно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы же сами выгружаете ленивую коллекцию сразу двумя способами в `PersonRepository#getAll`:

1. Репозиторий помечен аннотацией `@Transactional`, следовательно все методы тоже. Поэтому даже просто вызывая `person.getCards()` коллекция будет выгружаться.
2. `Hibernate#initialize` выгружает ленивую коллекцию, если транзакция активна, что вы и делаете.

Если хотите словить `LazyInitializationException`, не выгружайте коллекции в цикле метода `PersonRepository#getAll`.